# What willl be the fast method for a domain store in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I want to store domain names(example:google.com - without "http://" and "www")in MySQL as primary key+Index.

so when I call a domain through PHP I should get the result according to that domain faster.
Right now I am inserting domain in plain text.

is it right way to do it?? or do I need to hash it??

your Ideas please

Comment: You shouldn't strip off the www.  Just because www.somedomain.com and somedomain.com point to the same webserver, doesn't mean that they're actually the same domain.  Technically, www is a subdomain.

Comment: In MySQL (and probably all the other RDBMS) primary keys are also indexed, so yo do not need to use indexes on primary key field.

Comment: I mean Unique Index. but what about the method?? is this plain text format is ok?? I feel searching domain names in my database seeks more time..I am not sure of actual cause but start with one by one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should not use char/varchar in primary index. Rather create an int PK and domain column with unique constraint.

I think that would work in your case.

Checkout some reasons here:

[CHAR() or VARCHAR() as primary key in an ISAM mySQL table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164991/char-or-varchar-as-primary-key-in-an-isam-mysql-table)

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?153,243809,243818#msg-243818

---

EDIT

Here is the sample table. I created this table on assumptions. Change it according to your need.

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test`.`sample` (

  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,

  `domains` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,

  UNIQUE INDEX `domains_UNIQUE` (`domains` ASC) );
```

P.S. Created using mysql workbench.

Comment: can you draft a sample table?? I am not very familiar with MySQL

Comment: Great Thanks?? one question why domains_UNIQUE?? you already mentioned as UNIQUE INDEX

Comment: @mathew - It is name of the index.