# Webview don't show letter from input on Android?

Tags: android, webview

I have a problem with `WebView`, I use zsseditor with `WebView` to show, input text from keyboard, insert image or video. And then, I can't delete newest letter in paragraph (almost I can't delete image html tag). And I solved that problem by CustomWebview to delete image html tags.

```
public class CustomWebView extends WebView {


/**
 * Constructs a new WebView with a Context object.
 *
 * @param context a Context object used to access application assets
 */
public CustomWebView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

/**
 * Constructs a new WebView with layout parameters.
 *
 * @param context a Context object used to access application assets
 * @param attrs   an AttributeSet passed to our parent
 */
public CustomWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

/**
 * Constructs a new WebView with layout parameters and a default style.
 *
 * @param context  a Context object used to access application assets
 * @param attrs    an AttributeSet passed to our parent
 * @param defStyle the default style resource ID
 */
public CustomWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14560344/android-backspace-in-webview-baseinputconnection
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164991Image78/cant-get-backspace-to-work-in-codemirror-under-phonegap-on-android-4-x
@Override
public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs) {
    return new MyCustomInputConnection(this, false);
}

public class MyCustomInputConnection extends BaseInputConnection {

    public MyCustomInputConnection(View targetView, boolean fullEditor) {
        super(targetView, fullEditor);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean deleteSurroundingText(int beforeLength, int afterLength) {
        // magic: in latest Android, deleteSurroundingText(1, 0) will be called for backspace
        if (beforeLength == 1 && afterLength == 0) {
            // backspace
            return super.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL))
                    && super.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL));
        }

        return super.deleteSurroundingText(beforeLength, afterLength);
    }
    }
    }
```

I swap input keyboard to Japanese, Vietnamese, Thai or every language not Alphabet. But when I tap button letter on keyboard, it doesn't show on `WebView`. So how can I fix the `WebView` which can show letter with every language?

Comment: I solved it by other way without using img tags

Answer (score 1):

I have error same problem with you and solve with this code 
you just override inside your webview

```

```
@Override
  public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs) {
      outAttrs.actionLabel = null;
      outAttrs.inputType = InputType.TYPE_NULL;
      final InputConnection con = new BaseInputConnection(this,false);
      public_con = new InputConnectionWrapper(
              super.onCreateInputConnection(outAttrs), true) {
          @Override
          public boolean deleteSurroundingText(int beforeLength, int afterLength) {
              if (beforeLength == 1 && afterLength == 0) {
                  return this.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL))
                          && this.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL));
              }
              return super.deleteSurroundingText(beforeLength, afterLength);
          }

          @Override
          public boolean sendKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
              if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL){
                  return con.sendKeyEvent(event);
              }else {
                  return super.sendKeyEvent(event);
              }
          }
      };
      try {
          return public_con ;
      }catch (Exception e){
          return super.onCreateInputConnection(outAttrs) ;
      }
  }
```

```